# Why does this SQL syntax produce empty feature class with ArcGIS Select_analysis?

Tags: arcpy, sql, select

I'm working on a script that involves an arcpy.select_analysis function. The problem I have is that when I run the script it produces an empty file. I've verified that the whole thing works when in the Select GUI, and produces the correct output, and then have even exported the SQL expression and copy/pasted it into the arcgis python window, but no dice.

[image: Here is the script and warning in ArcGIS python window]

[image: Here is the table view showing that zip 10004 does exist in this field.]]

I've zoomed the extent both way out and way in to see if that makes a difference, but it doesn't. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is ZIP an Integer or Text field?  I'm guessing Text from the syntax that you have tried but want to confirm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

```
"'ZIP' = '10004'"
```

try this:

```
'"ZIP" = ' + "'10004'"
```

The reason that your original expression gives an empty output is because the string 'ZIP' is not the same as (equal to) the string '10004'.

Comment: thanks a ton! Your explanation makes sense, but for edifying clarification, why then is that the format of the expression in the SQL GUI?

Comment: In the SQL GUI the syntax is "ZIP" = '10004' but what you posted had single quotes around both field and value.  I'm happy to admit that I find getting SQL syntax right with Python/ArcPy can prove finicky.

Comment: finicky indeed! I pasted the single quotes in as for some reason that's how it exported, even though "ZIP" = '10004'was what was in the GUI. Thanks again

Comment: If you are doing a quick test/hack this would work fine. However, when running bigger scripts with multiple data sources (personal,file,SDE geodatabases,shapefiles), the SQL syntax can be hard to manage. Consider using the http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000006p000000, AddFieldDelimiters, which adds field delimiters to a field name to allow for use in SQL expressions.